# Xml data in DataGrid with XmlDataProvider doesnt show up at runtime

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid

I want to show an external xml file in my datagrid.
In designer it shows me the correct data, but if I run my app, the data doesn't show up in my datagrid anymore. Did I miss something?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" Source="Events.xml" XPath="Events"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{StaticResource Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Entrys}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding XPath=ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding XPath=Time}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding XPath=Type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Msg" Binding="{Binding XPath=Msg}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My Xml File:

```
<Events>
  <Entrys>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Time>23:44</Time>
    <Type>Follow</Type>
    <Name>xPowerbot</Name>
    <Msg>New Follower</Msg>  
  </Entrys>
</Events>
```

Comment: where is the Events.Xml file present ?, your Code is working perfectly. Checkout where is the fiel

Comment: i need to provide the full path in xmldataprovider source i found out.